# Parsing an XML file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have following xml file with same tags for the generic implementation .I want to parse this file .Can I parse this in iOS.

xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<node name="bkl">
    <childrens>
        <node name="A building">
            <childrens>
                <node name="hfs"/>
                <node name="habc"/>
                <node name="def"/>
            </childrens>  
        </node>
        <node name="B building">
            <childrens>
                <node name="hfs2"/>
                <node name="habc2"/>
                <node name="def2"/>
            </childrens>
        </node>
        <node name="C building">
            <childrens>
                <node name="hfs3"/>
                <node name="hab3"/>
                <node name="def3"/>
            </childrens>
        </node>

    </childrens>
</node>
```

Comment: Try `NSXMLParser`. Also, `childrens ` is not an English word.

Answer (score 0):

Youd should read [XML Parsing Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html) from the iOS Developer Library.

It describes how to parse an XML file using `NSXMLParser`.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. make counters for your depth. that is in start element method of parser, increment nodeHeight++ if it's a node element, and childern++ if childeren is the element and process

Answer (score -1):

You can parse this file with trick. For first time whenever childrens tag become close dont add item in array, After first time you can add items in array